# How to disable IsFeedEnabled() in test class

Tags: apex

I am writing test class and i am stuck on below code.

I `r.IsFeedEnabled()` always returning true value i want to go on else statement , ho can i achieve below task, just i want to cover else statement, please help me.

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = User.sObjectType.getDescribe();        

 if(r.IsFeedEnabled())
 {
    isChatterEnabled = true;
 }
 else
 {
    isChatterEnabled = false;
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're strictly concerned about code coverage, just assign the value directly:

```
isChatterEnabled = User.SObjectType.getDescribe().isFeedEnabled();
```

You might also use a @TestVisible variable to accomplish your goals:

```
@TestVisible static Boolean disableChatter = false;
...
isChatterEnabled = (!disableChatter) && User.SObjectType.getDescribe().isFeedEnabled();
```

I personally don't like this approach, because mixing in test code with real code is undesirable, but sometimes unavoidable.

Finally, you could always just create a user with a profile that has this feature disabled, and use the System.runAs feature to run your code as that user. This process may be relatively time-consuming, but would at least be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast Schema.DescribeSObjectResult into your own inner class and set member properties according to your need.

Comment: Realy i am not understand what are you saying.